# Accessing Microsoft Team Foundation Server website from a MAC

Tags: c#, ios, macos

Has anyone here tried to access TFS's web access from Mac OS using safari?  I get a server not found error.  On Windows, it works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is this tagged as iOS related?

Comment: Because some one that is developing for iOS may use TFS as their source/bug tracking repository.  If so, they can answer this.